# Menu in C# to be used on Classic ASP pages

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I created a menu which changes as per the role logged in. So, this is created in the master page. So, I would like to use this same menu once logged in on every asp page. Since, I'm not much into asp(VB especially), the idea I have is to create a menu in a  asp page and include it in all the other pages. But I just like to know if there is another way i can handle this like using the menu in the master page to be used on classic asp pages..can u help me out?

Comment: The question is very unclear, but if I understand you correctly, you created a menu in C# for an ASP.NET application, and you would like to recreate the menu for use in a classic ASP site. Does that sound about right?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you on the integration part since I have not worked with an integrated environment before.  But I do know enough about both to tell you that you probably do not want to try to implement the menu in classic asp.  There are a number of infrastructure pieces such as sitemap support and security-based trimming that are utilized in the asp.net menu that would be a real bear to implement in classic ASP.  So I would support a hybrid approach like what James Johnson is suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked on a few sites that integrated classic ASP pages with ASP.NET.

One option is to put the menu in a master page, and create an ASPX page to load your classic ASP pages using Server.Execute. That way, the menu and the site layout would be in ASP.NET, and your content pages would be classic ASP.

Using this approach, you would obviously have to remove all formatting from your ASP pages so ASP.NET can handle the layout. Your ASP pages would be purely content - kind of like master pages and content pages.

Comment: Hey sorry.. But i guess i should have included classic asp in the question..... i have updated the question now

Comment: @user838359: Is the whole site classic ASP, or are the classic ASP pages integrated with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

if all the other pages use the same master then it will appear on them also. You can have masters that have masters if some need to have different masters.

Alternatviely you could move it into a user control and add that onto the pages where required

Comment: hey I think, no master pages concept in Classic ASP

Comment: oh you mean classic asp, its not that clear in your question...good luck with that, I dont know much at all about classic asp. You might want to make it a bit clearer in the question though.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT
Forget it, you mean classic ASP? Not clear in your question, sorry.
EDIT**

I would place a ContentPlaceHolder in the Master Page that contains a LoginView control.  Use the various templates (e.g. LoggedInTemplate, AnonymousTemplate, RoleGroups) of the LoginView to display the menu you want based on your needed criteria.  The reason for putting the LoginView control in a ContentPlaceHolder is so that your Pages that use the Master can easily replace or remove the menu if needed.

Comment: Hey sorry.. But i guess i should have included classic asp in the question..... i have updated the question now